# How to specify c++0x flag on cent os

Tags: g++, c++11, centos

The command `g++ -o myprogram myprogram.c -std=c++0x` works well on ubuntu but when I try the same with centos it throws me an error `cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option "-std=c++0x"`. Even google doesn't give the answer. Have anybody experienced it before? Does anybody know the solution?

Comment: Do `g++ --version` and tell us what it says.

Comment: you have old compiler, update

Comment: g++ --version says "g++ (GCC) 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-48). I tried to yum install g++/c++ but it said "nothing to do". How can i update it to g++4.4?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You most likely have different versions of the compiler on each system, run `g++ --version` to see which version you're running on each (`-std=c++0x` is only supported from version 4.4 of g++).

Comment: You can always download the TAR file and build it yourself: http://gcc.gnu.org/install/

Answer (score 1):

In the CentOS repositories is something called `g++44`. Yum it, or grab it however makes the most sense to you.

Then, when you build, use `g++44...` with the rest of your switches. That might help, you never know.

If it works for you then you could remove `g++` and `symlink g++44`.